# vue.js pass input data to another page and submit vue method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is my first question and hope to receive your support.

I have catalogue page with keyword search and main page with search bar.

My goal is every time when someone submit the main search to redirect the call to the catalogue search and submit the keyword search method there.

```
<button class="searchword" @click="search()"></button>
```

On the destination url I have the following method:

```
search: function() {
                this.search.keyword = this.search.value;
                this.submit_form();
            },
```

Comment: If it works within the flow of your application, instead of having the search bar in the main component and the actual search functionality in the catalogue component, you might want to consider combining the search bar and search functionality in the same component.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow, Denitsa,
I think what you're looking for is

```
this.$router.push({name:'catalogue-search', params:{keyword:this.search.value})
```

and you would have a router.js where you define your pages.

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#html

and then on your CatalogueSearch page you will have access to

```
this.$route.params.keyword
```

Notice that you push to '$router' but you get the value from '$route'.